# I have column entries mixed with multiple "_" character, how can I replace the figure before the first "_" with a function while leaving the rest

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, replace

I have column entries that have characters mixed with multiple '_ ' (e.g. `67_0000100-478_NA_d202xz97406_t17199m2156`).

Using SQL (DB is Postgres), I want to replace only the figure before the first `'_'`  with a function (e.g. its square + itself) while leaving the remaining character the same way.

Current entry: `67_0000100-478_NA_d202xz97406_t17199m2156`

Desired output: `4556_0000100-478_NA_d202xz97406_t17199m2156`

Based on my research and exploring useful closely related previously answered questions on this platform, I figured most problem cases were for replacing/ deleting some texts when the text entries only have the character occurring just once.

My progress so far (Updated based on suggested comments), however I am getting syntax error (I am not an SQL expert):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_events AS
SELECT uid, serial_id, session_id, start_time, code, event_name, end_timestamp, temp_code
FROM public.events_data
update public.v_events
    set uid = concat(
                       (split_part(uid, '_', 1))::int^2 + (uid), 
                       substr(uid, strpos(uid, '_')))
```

Note: The uid is the column entry to be replaced with the function (uid^2 + uid). I understand that can be done using Power() in SQL.

What I need done is to create a view (public.v_events) of the original table (public.events_data) and replace only the figure before the first '_' (e.g. 67) with a different function (uid^2 + uid).

I would really appreciate help from anyone?

Comment: Are you sure this is [tag:postrgresql]? The question is tagged with it, but `charindex` isn't a PG function

Comment: Postgres has similar function `position()` but definitely does not support `charindex`, which is SQL Server.

Comment: @Mureinik my database is actually Postgresql and not SQL Server

Comment: Thanks @Stu, I agree

Comment: @Dipops I edited my MSSQL version below to convert it to a working Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption this is actually SQL Server (because of the use of *charindex*), here is a simple method you can use.

If your database actually *is* Postgres it has easily substitutable string functions you can use.

```
select mytext, Stuff(mytext, 1, p.pos, n.v*n.v) as Replaced /* implement desired function here */
from t
cross apply (values(CharIndex('_',mytext)-1))p(pos)
cross apply (values(Try_Cast(Left(mytext,p.pos) as int)))n(v)
```

Edit

Converting the above to a Postgres version:

```
select MyText, overlay(MyText placing cast(n.v*n.v as varchar(5)) from 1 for p.pos)
from t
join lateral (select position('_' in mytext)-1 pos) p on true
join lateral (select cast(Left(mytext,p.pos) as int) v)n on true;
```

[DB<>Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=02d3b4c387ea7fcc374c716070f743c4)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the square of the first element can be done e.g. using `split_part()` this can then be concatenated with the rest of the string:

```
update the_table 
    set the_column = concat(
                       (split_part(the_column, '_', 1))::int^2, 
                       substr(the_column, strpos(the_column, '_'))
                     )
```

`(split_part(the_column, '_', 1))::int` returns the string before the first `_` as an integer. It will result in an error if the value cant be converted to an int.

If you don't want to change the table, use that expression in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT concat((split_part(uid, '_', 1))::int^2 + (uid), 
               substr(uid, strpos(uid, '_'))) as uid, 
       serial_id, 
       session_id, start_time, code, event_name, end_timestamp, temp_code
FROM public.events_data
```

Comment: I updated the question based on your suggestion. I am getting syntax error.

Comment: You can't put an UPDATE statement into a view. You need to use a SELECT expression